# What to do when direct substitution tells us that limit does not exist but in actual it does exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I am learning limits these days and I have reached at finding limits by direct substitution but there's one that doesn't making sense to me at all. Let me illustrate it with an example $f(x) = x/x$ .The limit ( as $x$ approaches $0$) in this case does exist but by direct substitution, it says limit does not exist. What to do when you come across this type of questions.

Comment: You can cross out the $x$ and get $1$. This is a really broad question, but usually it is a substitution or an algebraic manipulation. Keep in mind that if the function is not continuous then you cannot use direct substitution.

Comment: Direct substitution? whatever that is it sounds worrying...

Comment: You cannot use substitution in a point where the functions is *not* defined.

Comment: Could you explain what the "direct substitution" thing you're talking about is? What do you substitute with what where, and how does that tell you that the limit doesn't exist? We can't tell you how your reasoning goes wrong unless you show us that reasoning.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question, in which circumstances you can't find limit by direct substitution?

Comment: 0/0 does not imply the limit does not exist. It could be determined by other methods which you would come across later [suppose you are reading a book or taking some class].

Comment: The sentence "but by direct substitution, it says limit does not exist" is *wrong*. What is true however is the following: The given expression for $f$ is *undefined* at $x=0$; hence "direct substitution" produces no value. Exactly for such cases we have the exception handling measure called "limit".

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave, as you're taking the limit when $\;x\to0\;$ , it is your right *and duty* to consider number "very close" to zero **but different** from zero. Under this understanding, we simply have $\;\cfrac xx=1\;$ for each number like this,and we can then easily deduce (according to its definition) the limit, which is 1.

In some other cases, as with $\;\cfrac{\sin x}x\;$ , taking close values of $\;x\;$ to zero gives values close to $\;1\;$ , yet the *formal proof* that $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\cfrac{\sin x}x=1\;$ is a little messier, though much prettier, and it is usually done by geometric arguments.

Resuming: every case must be considered separatedly, but sometimes, as in your example, you can do simple arithmetic manipulations and get your result pretty simply.

Comment: Let's take f(x) = x+2/x-1  Now, by direct substitution , you can't find limit (as x approaches 1). But, in real, it does exist

Comment: @BilalSheikh The limit of your function at $1$ does not exist. The limit on the right ($x>1$) is $+\infty$, whereas the limit on the left ($x<1$) is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Use other methods!

I don't hope anybody has tried to tell you that substitution works when the expression isn't defined, because (as your example shows) it doesn't.

In this case, you just need a simple algebraic manipulation to transform the expression you had to find the limit of into something else that is defined at the point (and therefore it's different), where you can "substitute" (there are no $x$'s left so it's a very trivial substitution in this case).